# how to use SLDS Icons in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, slds

I have `slds-nav-vertical` which will iterate the list with the icon. I'm using `slds-icon_container` But icon is not coming it's Look like Below.

[image]

On clicking the above link getting following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'menuItemId' of undefined throws at`

```
  <template for:each={studentdata} for:item="stu" for:index="index">
                                <div class="demo-only slds-p-left_xx-large" key={stu.Id}>
                                    <nav class="slds-nav-vertical" aria-label="Sub page">
                                        <ul aria-describedby="entity-header">

                                            <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
                                                <a class="slds-nav-vertical__action" data-menu-item-id={stu.Id}
                                                    aria-current="true" onclick={studentInformation}>
                                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account"
                                                        title="Description of icon when needed">
                                                        <svg class="slds-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                                                            <use
                                                                xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account">
                                                            </use>
                                                        </svg>
                                                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Description of icon when
                                                            needed</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                    {stu.Name}</a>
                                            </li>   </ul>

                                    </nav>
                                </div>
                            </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard components for the verticle navigation.

1. lightning-vertical-navigation
2. lightning-vertical-navigation-section
3. lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon

Here is the sample code.

```
<lightning-vertical-navigation selected-item="reports_recent">
    <lightning-vertical-navigation-section label="Reports">
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon label="Accounts" name="reports_recent" icon-name="standard:account">
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon>
        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon label="Contacts" name="reports_usercreated" icon-name="standard:contact">
        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon>
    </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
</lightning-vertical-navigation>
```

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-vertical-navigation/example)

### Or

Use `lightning-icon` component, it's prebuilt in LWC framework.

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" alternative-text="Account" title="Account"></lightning-icon>
```

All SLDS icons are supported out of the box in this component.

Refer to detailed [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/example).

You can also get the icon on the button by just specifying the name of the icon.

```
<lightning-button label="Neutral"  icon-name="standard:account" title="Non-primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

Comment: It's s vertical tab, which we need to display the sub tab with the hyperlink for that i need to add Icon for that.

Comment: lightning-icon wil not able to add label, In my case it will not be used as expected

Comment: @user3214361 You can do that actually, check the [playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/C5Hrqyus2OG7agzFOeZr/src/app.html)